# Can I inspect a Windows installer (cab/msi/exe) to see what changes it plans to make to my system?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installer

Clearly most installers do more than unpack files. Is there a file in there somewhere that lists planned actions?

Comment: Depends on who packaged the installer, your question is too broad.

Comment: I have never seen an installer you could tell everything it is going to do.